# looking for a way to check an elf binary for CUs missing dwarf info/data

Tags: elf, dwarf

I'm looking for a way to check an elf binary for CUs missing dwarf info/data.
I wondering if there is already a tool to do this?

I figure it can it can be done by building a map of what is described by the available dwarf data and then listing any holes. Just don't want to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.